# Make a class implement a Interface using Android Bindings in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm developing an Android application using Xamarin. For this app, I'll need to use two **.jar** libraries. These libraries do **exactly** the same thing, the difference is only that one should be used in a production environmentand the other is for development usage.

One of the requirements for that application, is that it must have a configuration that the user can set, to specify the environment (Production or Development).

I need to interact with a class of those libraries (let's call it `Foo`). If I needed to create that class using C#, I would first create an interface named `IFoo` and then create the two classes implementing that interface, then I would use a **factory** to create the correct instance based on the preference that the user set. But the problem is that on the **Java** libraries, both of those classes inherith directly from `Object`, so my calling code will not be able to use an abstraction as I wanted.

I was wondering, if it's possible to use the **Metadata transform** to modify the generated code to make the classes implement an interface. I was able to make it work by modifing the generated code, but every time I recompile the project, I miss my modifications.

Comment: You could probably use `<add-node>` appropriately to specify the specifics of what you want the class/interface to do:

https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb#adding-types

You should look through your generated `api.xml` for the definition of your `Foo` interface for a scaffolding to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generated classes are `partial`. This means that you can extend them easily.

**generated**

```
[global::Android.Runtime.Register ("com/bar/baz/Foo", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
public partial class Foo : global::Java.Lang.Object {

}
```

**addition**

Add this (Foo.cs) to the folder Additions

```
public partial class Foo : IFoo 
{
    public void WhatEverFooDoes() 
    {
        // implement me
    }
}
```

IFoo can define methods that are implemented by the generated code as well. So you just have to extract the interface from one of you classes, if the signature is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks Sven! I didn't notice those generated classes were partial.